# Programme Qutting on user input of text instead of integer value

Tags: c#, int, boolean

Just going through my code and I'm trying to solve an issue when testing for how can I get the programme to stop quitting the console when a user enters an option in the menu in text form for example they want to choose option "1" but decide to type the word "one" instead.

Thanks
Dan

```
int numNumbersReqd = 5;
            int chosenOption = 0;
            bool quit = false;

            Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("* This application is designed to allow you to select the number of numbers *");
            Console.WriteLine("* you wish to enter, and sum the numbers that you provide.                  *");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");

            while (quit == false)
            {
                DisplayMenu();
                chosenOption = ReadNumber("Please choose an option:");
                quit = ProcessMenu(chosenOption, ref numNumbersReqd);

            }

        }

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select an option");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add numbers");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Change amount of numbers to be entered");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Quit");
        }

        static int ReadNumber(string prompt)
        {
            string text;
            int number;


            Console.Write(prompt);
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            number = int.Parse(text);

            return number;
        }

        static bool ProcessMenu(int option, ref int numNumbers)
        {
            bool quit = false;

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    int total;
                    total = GetTotal(numNumbers);
                    DisplayResult(total); // Programme was initally set to display the option that the user had entered from "displayMenu", by changing the variabel from option to total it will now display the answer of the numbers entrered by the user
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numNumbers = ReadNumber("Please enter the number of numbers to be entered:");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    quit = IsQuitting();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unknown option value entered");
                    break;
            }

            return quit;
        }

        static int GetTotal(int numbersReqd)
        {
            int total;
            int index;

            total = 0;

            for (index = 0; index < numbersReqd - 1; index++)
            {
                total = total + ReadNumber("Please Enter Number:");
            }

            return total;
        }

        static void DisplayResult(int total)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("###############################################################################");
            Console.WriteLine("###############################################################################");
            Console.WriteLine("##################                     " + total.ToString() + "                     ##################");
            Console.WriteLine("###############################################################################");
            Console.WriteLine("###############################################################################");
        }

        static bool IsQuitting()
        {
            string response;
            bool quit = false;

            Console.Write("Do you really wish to quit?");

            response = Console.ReadLine();
            response = response.ToLower();

            if (response == "yes") // Problem fixed with quit option, "YES" used before was specifying uppercase only inputs which are highly unlikely to be entered by the user which caused the programme to loop back to the start menu,
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quiting");
                quit = true;
            }

            return quit;
```

Comment: Your code, as is, cannot compile since it's missing the method declaration for the first method. Also, your question is not very clear, please try to rephrase it.

Comment: Instead of int.Parse use int.TryParse to check if the user entered a valid integer and if not then you can prompt again (with an extra message that the input was not valid).

Comment: ok great thanks mark!

Comment: just tried to change to int.TryParse(text) but its showing an error

Comment: @DanLewis See my answer. `TryParse` takes two parameters, not one. A string to parse, and an int to `out` the value to. It returns true or false if the conversion was successful-- which is why it requires 2, since it doesn't just return the value like `Parse` does.

Comment: its just worked :D thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
int number;

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) // make sure that the user enters a valid number
    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid number");
// here number will have the value entered by the user.
```

`TryParse` will return `true` or `false` if the first parameter is a valid integer, and that value gets assigned to the second parameter using the `out` keyword.

"Regular" `Parse` will either convert the string to an integer, or throw an exception if it's not a valid integer.

Edit: cFrozenDeath suggested a good edit to my post, which encases the `TryParse` in a `while` loop. Effectively, what this is doing, is it will get input from the user UNTIL they enter a valid number. It is generally considered a good idea; if they enter in something incorrectly on accident, you most likely don't want to just immediately quit / end the program.

However, there is no logic in the `while` condition to *also* check if the value is "valid" from a requirements stand point. Your menu has 3 options, but if they enter 100 they've entered a mathematically valid integer but not a valid integer for your application. So you might want to also add a condition or two to check that `number` is within the acceptable range.

Comment: Why Int16 when the OP is talking about Int32? The TryParse method should also be directly in the if statement for cleaner code.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath What indicates it should be an `Int32` instead? He's just using `int.Parse()`-- does that default to `Int32`? Since he's only got options for 1-3, I figured I'd just go with something smaller

Comment: In c#, int is the shorthand for Int32

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Thanks, I was not aware of that. Editted my post to use 32 instead.

Comment: That's better, but I'd rather use directly int.TryParse(). Visual Studio 2015 would tell you "the name can be simplified" if you wrote Int32.TryParse()

Comment: Seems like a matter of personal preference. I use the capitalized type when referencing static methods / values, like `String.Empty` instead of `string.Empty` or `IntX.TryParse(s, out n)` instead of `int.TryParse(s, out n)`.

Comment: ok great, thanks all for your input/take on things. My biggest concern is that if a user enters for instance "one" instead of the integer "1". The programme is qutting automatically. I need it to loop back to the start menu or at least warn them. The while loop youve created seems great but doesn't seem to go with my function of static int ReadNumber(string prompt)   its throwing out errors.

Comment: @DanLewis Can you edit your post with the updated code? Don't need everything, just the `ReadNumber` method. It's more than likely just a silly mistake and should be simple to fix I think.

Answer (score -2):

You can use use int32.TryParse() instead of int.Parse().
The value will be 0 when the parsing failed and you can then act accordingly.

Comment: The value would also be 0 if the user actually entered a "0". You should check the return value of TryParse for true/false instead.

Comment: "When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed" << MSDN. As Mark said, what if the user actually entered "0"? You have no way of discerning if the conversion was successful or not. That's why it returns a bool and `out`s the integer instead. So look at its return value, not the numeric value.